Problem Uploading to Bigquery Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[0]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTag
Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[0]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields1' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields2' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields3' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields4' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[5]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[6]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[7]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[8]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[9]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[10]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[11]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[12]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[13]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[14]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[15]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[16]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'. Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[17]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'.
Tracking number: c1723409449619501
How can i solve this problem, it was okay back then because this is my daily upload, but this time got this error, can someone help?
I used to upload it daily, it doesn't have any problem but now got this problementer image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here

Welcome to Stackoverflow!!! ... I think we are going to need more context on the problem.   Can you read this article
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
and then contrast what is described there against your own question.  See if you can't think of ways to improve the question content.

i just do my daily upload, i didn't got any problem until then, just trying to upload my CSV file and append to the existing table

I got the same issue on the same day as you.
As a test, try to upload your file without a header in your csv - it should go through.
I started a thread here - see below:
The column headers of the csv file I upload contain spaces.
i.e. one of the column headers in the csv is 'Completed Date'.
In the past, BigQuery would upload this as Field Name = Completed_Date. Anytime I would upload a csv file, the header would remain the same ('Completed Date') and would go through without any issues.
Something must have changed since June 3 (last time I uploaded any csv files), as now, BigQuery uploads the same Field without the underscore hence the error I get (which sucks to get as an error as it doesn't explain what is a very simple error).
The field name is now 'Completed Date'.
See screenshot below, on the left is the schema and field names the way they would get uploaded. On the right, is how it shows and where the column headers from csv files now have to match 100% field names.
enter image description here
